# Angular 2 Material Tabs with double Label?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there any option to make an double label for Material Tabs? I have made a custom label like this:

```
<ng-template mat-tab-label>
                <div>{{mainTab.label}}</div>
                <div>{{mainTab.label}}</div>
            </ng-template>
```

But those two div's keep overlapping each other, is there any way to make them each on new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout of items in the tab label are controlled by the parent container through the class mat-tab-label-container. It is a flexbox layout. You can either override this, or what is probably much easier is to simply wrap everything in a single DIV:

```
<ng-template mat-tab-label>
    <div>
        <div>{{mainTab.label}}</div>
        <div>{{mainTab.label}}</div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Or if you just need simple mutli-line display, you can use BR:

```
<ng-template mat-tab-label>
    <div>{{mainTab.label}}<br>{{mainTab.label}}</div>
</ng-template>
```